# Text in SVG label is not showing for larger x and y coordinates

Tags: svg

My svg document have very high coordinates polygon is showing properly but text labels are not showing in drawing

```html
<svg id="svgcanvasEditor" width="1194" height="804" viewBox="9.214388E7 0 169528.0 189180.0">
  <g id="svgMainGroup" class="zoom-group">
    <g id="svgNewGroup" visibility="visible">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" style="overflow: visible;">
        <g id="drawing-svg-g" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 1.26455846E9)">
          <g>
            <polygon points="9.2259464E7,1.26449254E9 9.225948E7,1.26449869E9 9.2241272E7,1.26449869E9 9.2241256E7,1.26449254E9 9.2259464E7,1.26449254E9" stroke="blue" stroke-width="0.04%" fill="#E3E3E3">
            </polygon>
            <g transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 2528991232)">
              <text pointer-events="none" fill="blue" y="1264495616">
                <tspan text-anchor="middle" x="92250368" font-size="614.4px">HOVEDTAVLEROM</tspan>
                <tspan text-anchor="middle" x="92250368" dy="682.6666666666666" font-size="614.4px">8252</tspan>
                <tspan x="92250368" text-anchor="middle" dy="682.6666666666666" font-size="614.4px">113.75m2</tspan>
               </text>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Most browsers have limits on what they are prepared to work with. The answer is to use smaller numbers.

Comment: ``169528 / 1194`` = you are stuffing 115 "SVG pixels" into **1** screen pixel ?

Comment: https://oreillymedia.github.io/Using_SVG/extras/ch08-precision.html
Numbers cannot be more than floating point numbers browser don't handle those

Comment: You might try other SVG-export options in the original application (probably a CAD tool) like fit-to-page/size. The application might also support a pdf export that might help to flatten and re-scale the graphics to a reasonable page size. Then you could reconvert this pdf to a svg. Not ideal, but I'm afraid your current svg is quite lost (nested svgs, enormous transform and point values)